# Geometry nodes - Align Instance object to face orientation

Tags: normals, transform-orientation, geometry-nodes

Can someone tell me how to perfect align instanced object to face (normal orientation) ?
[image]

Blender File:
https://pasteall.org/blend/9e7e5be12367483586516dceba987699

Comment: Interesting problem. I think you need to find the top edge of the face and rotate along local Z by the angle this edge has in local space. Probably the hardest part of the problem is finding that edge. 

Comment: I'd love to know the answer too. The thing is that is works when you use face Instancing in the object properties, so the data is there. It should eventually be ported to a node socket.

Comment: @ChameleonScales the data is not there. The instances are aligned to the face normal, but the normal is just a vector. What OP asks for is to rotate the object around that vector, based on the angle of the top edge of the face in relation to that vector. But choosing the top edge, rather than any other edge of the face, is arbitrary.

Comment: The data **is** there. Faces have a preferred orientation in Blender. See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/j9Yhoz5.jpg. The issue is that only the "Object Properties" instancer knows to use it, not the node.

Comment: @ChameleonScales Hmmm... Yea, you're right, the preferred orientation is "Z up", that is, if you parent the arrows to an object, the green arrow going down will be going down on local Z of the parent. **But!** Look at the attached file, there there's just one object to which the arrows are being connected. So you don't have this information. So maybe I'm right after all.

Comment: From the attached file, using Object properties instancing: https://i.imgur.com/3ysikhk.jpg Parenting doesn't have anything to do with this issue. The method used to orient the instances here chooses an edge (like you suggested in the beginning). I don't know based on what though. Maybe the smallest index. I don't think we can do that with current Geo nodes but I think we can find a way to get the edge normal of the closest edge to the face center. That should at least straighten things up.

Comment: @ChameleonScales I think I was wrong and face orientation might be used. So just like a custom orientation set for a face sets Z to the normal and X and Y to the edges, it might be similar in this case. Still, it's "random", as in there's no way to control which edge is responsible for X, and which of the two adjacent edges is responsible for Y...

Comment: @Markus von Broady Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Following an edge or pointing to an edge in some way or another is the way to do it. I posted a hopefully temporary answer. Now to find a more consistent result. I think choosing the edge by smallest index would be the best because even if the results were not exactly as you wanted, you could simply rotate any face you want in edit mode.

Answer (score 2):

So Markus von Broady and I came up with this method which consists of rotating the normal towards the closest edge center and then rotating it again by 90° increments depending on which orientation is closest to your desired global (world) axis.

This lets you control which global axis to prioritize so that you can keep consistency across your geometry, which will depend on the shape and orientation of your object.

In the images below the pink dashed arrows point to the closest edge center.

Without prioritizing a global axis it would look like this, which has no consistency across the geometry but still follows face orientation in some way :

[image]

And then after prioritizing a global axis :

[image]

Here is the file :

[image]

Here is the main node tree :

[image: main node tree]

Here is the inside of "Prioritize Global axis" :

[image: prioritize global axis]

and here is the inside of "Choose axis" :

[image: choose axis]

Another useful method would be to point towards the edge which has the smallest index so that you'd have control over the face orientation in edit mode. I think however that it would require nodes that don't exist as of Blender 3.0.

Comment: Your setup has some problems because the gizmos sometimes sink below the noisy plane. I added two nodes to the main graph (one being a custom node), which rotate the vector in order to look for one pointing up (but as you can see this fails for triangles). Also don't ask why it's *less than* and not *greater than*, have been just playing around.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, that looks better. I noticed the sinking gizmos but I think it's just because the quads on the noisy plane are non planar, unlike those on the UV sphere.

Comment: I understand your method better now. It's great because it lets you control which global axis to prioritize. Still I think an index based approach would also be useful. There are a bunch of new Mesh nodes in 3.1 alpha. Maybe in the future this will be doable.

Comment: I edited the answer again.

Comment: After you convert edges to points, you can transfer attribute - position for the closest edge, take distance to the current position, boolean not, make that control the geometry removal node. Repeat a few times. This way you keep getting the nearest edge position, removing the point representing it, and getting 2nd nearest edge position, 3rd nearest and so on. This way you can sample all edges and just like with my solution with vectors, instead of rotating them (and assuming 90° angles), you can sample all edges and pick the highest.

Comment: Interesting idea but I'm not clear about what improvement it would bring. Also wouldn't it increase the risk of selecting an edge that doesn't belong to the face?

Comment: Right, you need to do split edges first. https://i.imgur.com/vQAPSi1.png

Comment: ok. I'm still not clear about what use case it could have though.

Comment: You could align the gizmo to the highest edge as opposed to a multiply of a 90° rotation from the nearest edge. Probably better. Or maybe you want to construct your gizmos in a different way, perhaps even change their shape depending on quad / triangle / ngon.

Comment: ok that clarifies it, thank you.